# Order by issue in msql query gives syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have this query here:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT 
matching.date,
matching.points,
matching.time,
matching.location,
matching.epos_id,
matching.time_added,
rbpos_epos.epos_id,
rbpos_epos.location
FROM
matching
LEFT JOIN
rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id
WHERE
matching.user_id = ".$id_user." LIMIT $start, $per_page ORDER BY matching.time_added DESC";
```

I get an error in the ORDER BY part, what is wrong, where should i put it? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have swapped the order of the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses. The ORDER BY clause comes first, then the LIMIT clause. This should work:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT 
matching.date,
matching.points,
matching.time,
matching.location,
matching.epos_id,
matching.time_added,
rbpos_epos.epos_id,
rbpos_epos.location
FROM
matching
LEFT JOIN
rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id
WHERE
matching.user_id = ".$id_user." ORDER BY matching.time_added DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$per_page;
```

Comment: i get this if i change it : MySql ErrorUnknown column 'A101' in 'where clause' ...

Comment: @AlbAlb I see there is another error where the `$start` and `$limit` variables were not properly added. I have edited my post, could you try again?

Answer (score 0):

The limit is always applied at the end of result gathering, therefore after order by.

Given all your clauses, the order of processing will be

- FROM
- WHERE
- SELECT
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT

So you will get the closest record <= publishedOn matching all the conditions in the WHERE clause.

@credit : RichardTheKiwi